# How to access fields that start with a number from SQL using SQLKata in .vb

Tags: sql, sqlkata

Using a queryFactory such as db.Query("Stuff).Select("2Dblue2").Get()

How would one access this value as field names cannot start with numbers

Comment: Easiest way `.Select("2Dblue2 as Dblue2")` and you can access it as `Dblue2`

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense thank you.